# How to increase visitors per day and get new users?

Tags: discussion

With now having more than 1,500 visitors/day we're already doing a good job. The only unsatisfying data is still the count of questions. The latter one, however, can only be increased by having users which do have questions.

For that reason I think we should focus on still increasing visitors/day. The more visitors, the more potential users.

What can we do?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming most visitors are not users of the stack exchange network but occasional visits via Google, we need to make sure that questions are likely to hit.

We have some questions that are too localized. For example they focus on one particular word. Another issue are questions that are tagged incorrectly or incompletely.

As example see this [recent question in its first revision](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/6882/1). Ignoring typos, the title does only convey partially what is being asked. The tag is completely wrong. On Stackoverflow this question would have vanished somewhere in the excess of questions without being noticed.

This, luckily, does not happen on GLU but this question will never find its way up in Google hits.

By editing such a question we can make this question more interesting and appropriate to other, potential users.

The question should have the most important keywords in the title. Keywords need to be repeated in body and tags. The question should not be focused on one particular word or phrase but on a group of words:

> *Wo kann 'aber' im Satz stehen?
>
> An welchen Positionen im Satz kann eine Konjunktion wie 'aber' gesetzt werden?

I think it's fine to add further examples because this question will still not be shown in Google when searching for, e.g., *jedoch*. (Though, tricky thing about *jedoch* is that the word order of subject and verb changes when *jedoch* is in the first position)

---

Actually, there's still one issue in this particular case. In the example sentence you can place the conjunction at three different positions. *Jedoch*, too, at least when changing word order appropriately. The conjunction *and*, for example, has only one correct position. I consider this, however, as missing information in the answer. Probably because the answer focus on this particular example. Is *aber* still a conjunction in case b? Has a conjunction to be in the first position? I wonder why we do not have such questions? People who are looking for this will probably not find us on Google. Bummer.

Comment: Interestingly another [remotely related question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6403/positions-of-verbs-in-clauses) found it's way on page 2 of a Google search for *"conjunction aber postition"* indicating how important tagging is. Still I dont get why the closer question did not make it.

Comment: Oh! When searching for *"aber position german"* the question mentioned does turn up on position 5 here. Its a matter of search terms people may have - these **need** to be predicted and they should occur somehwere in the title, tag or body.

Comment: Good thoughts, but... I don't mean to rain on anyone's parade but the German-speaking Q&A sites like Gutefrage, Cosmiq, Yahoo.de are firmly entrenched. Most of them appeared years before GLU and they have most of the mind share. Inertia is hard to overcome. The unique advantages of SE are the user interface, which is constantly being improved and refined, and "soft" factors: international membership with English as lingua franca (lots of opportunity for practicing), world-leading Q&A sites for IT professionals, a smattering of very good stackexchanges in fields like physics, math...

Comment: ... but it takes a long time for awareness to percolate into the broader public. In my opinion, SE needs to take some money in hand, partner with institutions like universities or educational associations, stage events in major cities: a marketing campaign plus PR blitz.

Comment: # of questions on GLU currently: 1,784. # of questions tagged "deutsch" on Cosmiq.de: 8,000+ (out of a total 3,000,000+). # of questions tagged "deutsch" on Gutefrage.net: 30,000+ (out of a total 10,000,000+). # of questions about German language and usage on Ask Yahoo: unknown but also very large. Yes, I am comparing apples and oranges. But the orange can hardly be seen underneath the pile of apples...